# Non integer number in the solution

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

[image]

Why in some cases the result is non-integer number, although the decision variable is an integer?

I use gurobipy to optimize the model.

Comment: Those values must be 1 and 0, to floating-point accuracy.

Comment: No, floating point accuracy is 1e-16. This has to do with tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

All MIP solvers use different tolerances. One of them is the integer feasibility tolerance. In Gurobi this is called **IntFeasTol**. By default it is 1.0e-5. As a result, variables are allowed to be slightly fractional. In most cases, you can round them to the nearest integer. Occasionally this rounding may cause constraints to become somewhat infeasible.

Comment: How would you extract the correct underlying integer value? I am thinking something like comparing the value to ceil(value) and checking if that absolute difference is small enough; if not checking if the value is close enough to floor(value)?

Comment: @MikkelLP Strictly speaking there really is no underlying integer value. If needed I convert a floating-point value to an integer using Python's round() function.

Comment: Yes ok, so rounding to 0 decimals will give you the nearest integer

Comment: @MikkelLP Warning  `round(x,0)` returns a float while `round(x)` returns an integer.